# Gene names from vmatchPattern (Biostrings)

Tags: r, bioinformatics, rna-seq

I try to get the gene names out of a binding analysis of the 5'UTR. Therefore I have this little code. Until the `vmatchPattern` everything works fine. At least I hope so.

```
library(biomaRt)
library(GenomicFeatures)
library(XVector)
library(Biostrings)
library(TxDb.Mmusculus.UCSC.mm10.knownGene)
library(BSgenome.Mmusculus.UCSC.mm10)

fUTR <- fiveUTRsByTranscript(TxDb.Mmusculus.UCSC.mm10.knownGene)

Mmusculus <- BSgenome.Mmusculus.UCSC.mm10
seqlevelsStyle(Mmusculus) <- 'ensembl'
seqlevelsStyle(fUTR) <- 'ensembl'

Seq <- getSeq(Mmusculus, fUTR)
Pbind <- RNAString('UGUGUGAAHAA')

Match <- vmatchPattern(Pbind, unlist2(Seq), max.mismatch = 0, min.mismatch = 0, with.indels = F, fixed = T, algorithm = 'auto')
```

Afterwards however I want to get the gene names to create a list in the end and use this in Python for further analysis of a RNAseq experiment. There comes a problem, I think I found so far three different ways on how to potentially do this. However none of them are working for me.

```
##How to get gene names from the match Pattern
#1
matches <- unlist(Match, recursive = T, use.names = T)
m <- as.matrix(matches)
subseq(genes[rownames(m),], start = m[rownames(m),1], width = 20)

#2
transcripts(TxDb.Mmusculus.UCSC.mm10.knownGene, columns = c('tx_id', 'tx_name', 'gene_id'))

#3
count_index <- countIndex(Match)
wh <- which(count_index > 0)
result_list = list()
for(i in 1: length(wh))  
{
  result_list[[i]] = Views(subject[[wh[i]]], mindex[[wh[i]]])
  
}
names(result_listF) = nm[wh]
```

I am happy to hear some suggestions and get some help or solution for this problem. I am no Bioinformation by training, so this took me already quite a while to figure this out.

Comment: is it chip seq analysis?

Comment: So the scRNAseq was a 10x genomics. But the approach that I am doing here is just on existing databases. However if there is a way to do the same on the RNAseq data then this would be even better.

Comment: Im still confused about the gene name part which you have asked what I do i would explain I do differential gene expression bulk rna seq then i get ensembl ID which i map to other gene IDs by making a table from HGNC database that part I dont do with R library. If you can explain a bit more in the question I would love to figure it out

Comment: I have a scRNAseq dataset. And I have a RNA binding Protein with a certain binding sequence in the 5'UTR. What I want to do is, get in general a list of genes/transcripts that have these binding sites in the 5'UTR. Therefore I started getting the transcripts from a mouse and try to find matches in the 5'UTR. The next thing that I want to do is, get the names of these transcripts and put them into a list and see if these are enriched in a certain cluster of the scRNAseq.
Why I started with R is that I found this Biostrings library to get the 5'UTRs and then search for matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found an answer, I hope this helps someone, and there is no mistake somewhere.

```
library(BSgenome.Mmusculus.UCSC.mm10)
library(TxDb.Mmusculus.UCSC.mm10.knownGene)
library(org.Mm.eg.db)

##get all 5’ UTR sequences
fUTR <- fiveUTRsByTranscript(TxDb.Mmusculus.UCSC.mm10.knownGene)
utr_ul <- unlist(fUTR, use.names = F)

mcols(utr_ul)$tx_id <- rep(as.integer(names(fUTR)), lengths(fUTR))
utr_ul

tx2gene <- mcols(transcripts(TxDb.Mmusculus.UCSC.mm10.knownGene, columns = c('tx_id', 'tx_name', 'gene_id')))
tx2gene$gene_id <- as.character(tx2gene$gene_id)

m <- match(mcols(utr_ul)$tx_id, tx2gene$tx_id)
mcols(utr_ul) <- cbind(mcols(utr_ul), tx2gene[m, -1L, drop = F])

utr5_by_gene <- split(utr_ul, mcols(utr_ul)$gene_id)

seqs <- getSeq(Mmusculus, utr5_by_gene)


##search with motif UGUGUGAAHAA
motif <- DNAString('TGTGTGAAHAA')
x <- vmatchPattern(motif, unlist(seqs), fixed = F)
matches <- unlist(x, recursive = T, use.names = T)


##list all genes with matches
hits <- mapIds(org.Mm.eg.db, keys = unique(names(matches)), keytype = 'ENTREZID',
               column = 'SYMBOL', multiVals = 'first')
```